# Convert internal array into index of outer array without using foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1127
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16101
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16441
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18447
        )
)
```

i want to convert the above array into this form:

```
Array
    (
        [0]  => 1120

        [1] =>  1127

        [2] => 16101

        [3] => 16441

        [4] => 18447
    )
```

but condition is this must be done **without using foreach**. Is this possible?

Comment: But why you dont want to use foreach function. What is the problem?

foreach function is good for this type of scenarios

Comment: the never ending array column answer

Comment: @Rajender because in my case there are thousand of entries, and if i use foreach or any other loop then it slow down the server speed.

Comment: @Insomania ok, you can use array_column function. 
For more information  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for PHP >= 5.5 - `array_column` function:

```
// assuming $arr is your initial array
$result = array_column($arr, 'id');

var_dump($result);
// the output:
Array
    (
        [0]  => 1120

        [1] =>  1127

        [2] => 16101

        [3] => 16441

        [4] => 18447
    )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: hats off!! man, thank you so much, SO always saves my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$final_array = array_column($your_array, "id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/array-column) to do this.

```
var_dump(array_column([['id' => 1],['id'=>2]], 'id'));

/*
gives you..

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_combine(array_keys($arr), array_map(function($item) { return $item['id']; }, $arr));
```

Comment: using bazooka to kill mosquito :)

Answer (score 0):

For PHP versions `>=4.0.6` you can simply use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like as

```
$arr = array(array('id' => 1),array('id' => 2),array('id' => 3));
function call_function($v){ 
    return $v['id'];
}
$result = array_map('call_function',$arr);
print_r($result);
```

Instead you can simply use [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function as [**@Ghost**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3859027/ghost) said like as

```
$arr = array(array('id' => 1),array('id' => 2),array('id' => 3));
$result = array_map('reset',$arr);
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/8HjQl)

Comment: or just simply `$result = array_map('reset', $arr)`

Comment: Yes you're right @Ghost I've updated my answer

Comment: Downvoters post the reason for downvoting. So I can improve my answer

Comment: i got the notification, actually that was my upvote, its funny yours has the only downvote here, you got a fan following you lol :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrFirstArray = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => 1120
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id' => 1127
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id' => 16101
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'id' => 16441
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'id' => 18447
        ));

echo $intFirstArray = count($arrFirstArray);

$arrSecondArray = array();
for ($intI = 0; $intI < $intFirstArray; $intI++)
{
    global $arrSecondArray;
    $arrSecondArray[] = $arrFirstArray[$intI]['id'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrSecondArray);
```

This will definitely work.